# C# namespace not visible

Tags: c#, namespaces

Using Visual Studio 2012, I have a solution with 4 projects, one of which is a web application - this is all in C#.

One of the projects (ApplicationServices) was referenced by the Web project and had some classes in a namespace of A.B.X let's say.  Recently, I needed a new set of classes for a similar service, so I copied the 3 .cs files that were in one folder and created a new folder and put them in there. (This is in the same project.)  I changed the namespace in the 3 files from A.B.X to A.B.Z.  Back in the other project that referenced A.B.X I tried adding a using of A.B.Z but it could not find it.

- All projects were .NET Framework 4.5, but I even tried changing to 4 but it did not help.  There are no references to Client Profile at all.
- The reference in the Web project that uses ApplicationServices is to the project, not to a DLL, but I removed and re-added that to make sure.
- The A.B.Z namespace has no errors/warnings, the entirety of ApplicationServices compiles just fine, no bad references.
- All of the classes in A.B.Z are public - as I said above, they are nearly clones of the ones in A.B.X.
- The default namespace in the assembly has not changed and is set to "A".
- I have cleaned, recompiled, even went so far as to wipe out the bin and obj folders for everything, re-loading VS2012 and the solution and rebuilding, but the namespace will NOT appear in the list of namespaces that I can reference via using, even though the classes that are mostly identical in the A.B.X namespace appear fine.

Here are the first few lines of one of the files with code in the assembly in a namespace that it DOES recognize:

```
namespace MarketCert.Parts.WordpressServices
{
    public class WordpressService
    {
        private const string WordpressEndpoint = "WordpressEndpoint";

        public WordpressUser Login(string username, string password)
        {
```

And here are the first few lines from one of the new (corresponding) files of code in the same assembly/project that is NOT recognized:

```
namespace MarketCert.Parts.YMServices
{
    public class YMService
    {
        private const string YMEndpoint = "YMEndpoint";
        private const string YMKeyName = "YMPublicKey";

        public YMUser Login(string username, string password)
        {
```

YMUser is defined in another one of the code files in the same namespace, so it is of course not recognized either...

I have run out of ideas!  Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Copying .cs files is not enough.  They have to included in a project and if you created a new project for them then you have to add a reference to that new project.

Comment: This was all done within the same project/assembly.